# Sliding window based on values (not index)

Tags: scala

I have a sparse list of timestamps, let's dumb it down to:

```
val stamps = List(1,2,3,7,10,11)
```

Imagine I have a window size of three, what would be a Scala/Functional way to get the following output

```
valueWindowed (3, stamps) == List(
  // Starting at timestamp 1 of stamps, we include the next values which are no bigger than the current value + the window size
  List(1, 2, 3), 
  // Starting at timestamp 2 include the next values in this window
  List(2, 3), 
  List(3), // ...
  // This one is empty as the window starts at timestamp 4 and ends at 6 (inclusive)
  List(), 
  // This one _does_ include 7, as the windows starts at 5 and ends at 7 (inclusive)
  List(7), 
  List(7), 
  List(7),
  List(10),
  List(10,11),
  List(10,11),
  List(11)
)
```

## Update

I have the following implementation, but it looks very procedural, jammed into functional constructs. Also the complexity is `max(stamps) * stamps size`

```
def valueWindowed(step: Int, times: List[Int]) = {
  for(j <- (1 to times.max).toIterator) yield{
    times.dropWhile(_ < j) takeWhile(_ < j+step)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't follow you. Can you describe in words what the constraints for each window are? Because it looks at first as if the sum of each window must be `< 10`, otherwise you would include `(3, 7)`, but then you have windows with sum `10`. Not clear what you ask for.

Comment: There is no summing or any operation done. I'll add a few more terms, hoping that you see the pattern.

Comment: I'm guessing you want *this* element, plus all following elements that are within 3 in value? But it's really not clear from your example (it's not helpful that you have three elements within a range of 3, and also the first element of the list is of length 3, for instance). And I don't understand where the empty list fits. Is the list guaranteed to be strictly increasing? (ordered, no duplicates)?

Comment: So `stamps = List(1, 1000)` gives `List(List(1), 999-empty-lists, List(1000))`?

Comment: To be pedantic it would be `List(List(1), 996 empty lists, List(1000), List(1000), List(1000))`. Which might seem weird in this very sparse dataset, but is actually adhering to the semantics for the defined window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a functional one that is O(N) - where N is the range of the numbers in `times`, not the length of it. But it's not possible to do better than that since that's the size of your output.

```
def  valueWindowed(step:Int, times:List[Int]) = {
(times :+ times.last+step)
    .sliding(2)
    .flatMap{case List(a,b) => Some(a)::List.fill(b-a-1)(None)}
    .sliding(step)
    .map(_.flatten)
}
```

The first `sliding` and `flatMap` expand the list so it has `Some(x)` for all x in `times`, and `None` for all intermediate values (adding a sentinel value to get the last element included correctly). Then we take `steps` windows and use `flatten` to remove the `None`/convert the `Some` back